# Opening A .URDF in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, urdf, solidworks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a .URDF from SolidWorks using SW2URDF plug in, but the model doesn't appear in the insert model list in GAZEBO, even after i paste relevant files in .Gazebo folder. I know its basic stuff but please help. How do I open my model in GAZEBO after creating a URDF from SOLIDWORKS.

Thankyou.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223987/opening-a-.urdf-in-gazebo/) by [Shoiab](https://answers.ros.org/users/25559/shoiab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a tutorial [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch) to open an urdf in Gazebo. (I don't know if you can have the urdf model in the gazebo list model)

You have two ways to do that :

1. Command line
   rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo

   rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find MYROBOT_description`/urdf/MYROBOT.urdf -urdf -x 0 -y 0 -z 1 -model MYROBOT (you must create a ros package)
2. Launch file

This node to start gazebo :

```
<launch>
    <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
      <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
      <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
      <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
      <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
      <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

This node to spawn a model :

```
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file $(find baxter_description)/urdf/baxter.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model baxter" />
```

---

Originally posted by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) with karma: 379 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John999990](https://answers.ros.org/users/38784/john999990/) on 2018-11-30**:
I went to all the trouble creating an account just to ask this:
Is it so fuc@@@@ hard to add a File->Open fuc&*&$ Menu?